# .NET Command line utilities, dumpbin.exe and coreflag.exe

Tags: .net

What exactly is the use of DUMPBIN.exe as well as COREFLAG.exe?? and when to use it??

Comment: Jared and Michael thanks for the answer :) !...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean corflag (no e)?  If so it's a utility used to change certain header properties of .Net executables.  Most commonly it's used to change the processor architecture of a .Net DLL.  Full documentation at

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699(VS.80).aspx

Less familiar with Dumpbin but the full documentation is here

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 3):

`dumpbin.exe` is just a utility that dumps various aspects of an executable image or .obj file (imports, exports, information in the header, etc).

A bit of trivia - `dumpbin.exe` is a simple program that just invokes `link.exe` with the `/dump` option. Or maybe it's the other way around.